# Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb F)$, s. t. $a_{ij} = i − j\;\forall i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Prove that $\det(A) = 0$.

Tags: matrices

Let $A = (a_{i j})\in M_n(\mathbb F),n\geq 3$,s. t. $a_{ij} = i − j,\;\forall i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Prove that $\det(A) = 0$.

I was thinking that I can prove that $\det(A)$ is $0$, by showing that the last row is $0$. But not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the Maths in your question nicely

Comment: **Hint:** Write $A$ as the difference of two rank-1 matrices.  Conclude that its rank is at most $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote $C_i$ the $i$th column of $A$.

We can make $C_1\leftarrow C_1-C_2$ and $C_2\leftarrow C_2-C_3$

The two first columns are equal so the determinant is 0.

Comment: +1 well done. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that given matrix is skew symetric, so $$A=-A^{\top}$$

so if $n$ is **odd** $$\det A = det(-A^{\top}) = (-1)^n\det(A^{\top}) = -\det A$$ and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = (1,\dots,1)^T$ and $y = (1,2,\dots,n)^T$.  It suffices to note that
$$
A = yx^T - x^Ty = \pmatrix{x & y} \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} \pmatrix{x & y}^T.
$$
It follows that $A$ has rank at most $2$.